# Does the law of large numbers hold with the Henstock–Kurzweil integral?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, gauge-integral

If I am understanding, the law of large numbers correctly, one implication is this:

Let $\lambda$ be the Lebesgue measure on $[0,1]$. Let $f_1,f_2,\dots,$ be functions, $[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, such that

1. (Identically distributed) For all $x \in \mathbb{R}$, for all $i,j \in \mathbb{N}$, \begin{align*}
   \lambda(\{\omega \in [0,1]: f_i(\omega) \leq x\}) = \lambda(\{\omega \in [0,1]: f_j(\omega) \leq x\})
   \end{align*}
2. (Independent) For all $x_1, \dots, x_k \in \mathbb{R}$, for all $\{i_1,\dots, i_k\} \subseteq \mathbb{N}$\begin{align*}
   &\lambda(\{\omega \in [0,1]: f_{i_1}(\omega) \leq x_1, \dots, f_{i_k}(\omega) \leq x_k\}) \\
   &= \lambda(\{\omega \in [0,1]: f_{i_1}(\omega) \leq x_1\})\cdots\lambda(\{\omega \in [0,1]: f_{i_k}(\omega) \leq x_k\})
   \end{align*}
3. (Integrable)
   $\int_0^1 f_1(\omega)d\lambda(\omega)$ exists and is finite.

Then there exists $A \subseteq [0,1]$ with $\lambda(A) = 1$ such that for all $\omega\in A$,
\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\omega) = \int_0^1 f_1(\omega)d\lambda(\omega)
\end{align*}

My question is: if we weaken the requirement that $f_1$ is Lebesgue integrable, and instead merely require that it is Henstock–Kurzweil integrable, does this theorem still hold? That is, does $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n f_i(\omega)$ converge to the Henstock-Kurzweil integral?

I ask this because if this theorem still holds, then that suggests that the Henstock–Kurzweil integral ought to be used instead of the Lebesgue integral, as we might encounter, for example, a statistical experiment where we have iid random variables that are not Lebesgue integrable, but are Henstock–Kurzweil integrable. In this situation, if we only considered Lebesgue integrability, we would conclude that the sample average does not converge, whereas in reality, it would, to the Henstock–Kurzweil integral.

Likewise, if it does not hold, then that suggests that the Lebesgue integral ought to be favored in the context of probability; otherwise we may mistakenly conclude that the sample average converges, when it does not.

In addition, this further raises the question of whether the (proper) Riemann integral may be superior to the Lebesgue integral in some situations. It seems to me that this is never the case in the context of probability, but perhaps it may be the case in, say, kinematics?

Comment: The Lebesgue integral is a strict extension of the proper Riemann integral, so that suggestion is out. Anyway, on the actual topic, is say $\frac{x}{1+x^2}$ HK integrable on $\mathbb{R}$? If so then there's a counterexample. I suspect something like this will cause the problem, due to the sort of "chaotic evaluation" that you get with Monte Carlo integration.

Comment: The fact that the Lebesgue integral is a strict extension of the Riemann integral is why I pose that question, by analogue to the fact that the HK integral is a strict extension of the Lebesgue integral–there may be some situations where Riemann integrability has some physical interpretation that the Lebesgue integral lacks.

Comment: The thing with making the domain $\mathbb{R}$ is that the Lebesgue measure is no longer a probability measure. You can't really define a statistical experiment where you draw a number uniformly out of all real numbers.

Comment: Just about anything other than piecewise continuous functions don't really physically mean anything most of the time. Also, incompleteness is pretty much fundamentally unsatisfactory for this kind of theory, so the point about proper Riemann integration is just kinda irrelevant. As for the point about $\mathbb{R}$, that's not the problem. The measure there is $\mu(A)=\int_A \frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+x^2} \, dx$. You can change variables to confine attention to $[0,1]$ if you want, but that's not necessary to get the point.

Comment: The point is that this is a probability distribution which is symmetric about $0$, so its expectation "must be zero if it's anything", but actually it isn't anything. And you see that in the failure of LLN in this example.

Comment: Wait, would $f(x) = \int_0^1 \frac{\text{logit}(x)}{1 + \text{logit}(x)^2}d\lambda(x)$ be equivalent? I put it into Wolfram Alpha and it says the integral is 0.

Comment: No, I don't think the singularity type is the same. You get the analogous singularity by doing something like $u=e^{-x}$ on the right and then $u=-e^x$ on the left. Then the domain is $[-1,1]$ which you can shift to $[0,1]$ however you like.

Comment: Oh wait, I realized I also forgot the $\frac{d}{dx}logit(x)$ term. Now the integral doesn't exist. Anyway, thank you, do you happen to have any resource on proving functions to be HK integrable?